# Generic implementation von java.util.Comparator in Scala

Tags: java, scala, twirl

I am using twirl templates with Java and Scala. So I am trying to sort a List in the template, but I do not know how to override the Comparator method.

My List contains objects of a class designed like:

```
class Foo extends BaseFoo<Foo>
```

The class BaseFoo does have a method called

```
public String FooName() {/*returns some Name of Foo*/}
```

In my scala twirl template it looks like:

```
source: java.util.Collection[_ <: BaseFoo[_]]
```

No in the twirl template I am trying to sort it:

```
@Collections.sort(
     new util.ArrayList[_ <: BaseFoo[_]](source),
     new Comparator[_ <: BaseFoo[_]] {
       override def compare(o1: BaseFoo, o2: BaseFoo) = {
             return o1.FooName.compareTo(o2.FooName);
       }
})
```

But this seems not to compile:

> class type required but java.util.ArrayList[_ <: BaseFoo[_]] found

Comment: I appreciate the accept. Is there anything else I could add to make the answer also upvote worthy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but given that you state that you have a list of Foo objects, the straight forward solution seems to be to use

```
source: java.util.Collection[_ <: Foo[_]]
```

or something alike!

Meaning: when the list contains Foo objects, what does it matter if those descend from Object or from FooBase?!

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your `source` to a Scala collection type and then just call `.sortBy` on it. No need for `Comparator`s:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
source.asScala.toSeq.sortBy(_.FooName)
```